# Attempt to read property "id" on null Auth::user() multiple authentication system

Tags: php, laravel

I implemented the multiple authentication system using the laravel Auth package.

But in route `example.com/admin/login` when I use this code:

```
dd(Auth::user()->id);
```

I get the following error:

> Attempt to read property "id" on null

**Note**: I do not have this problem in the default route of the Auth package, ie `example.com/login`.

Comment: Where are you executing this code.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy HomeController

Comment: And does HomeController have `web` middleware on it?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No, I realized my problem with your help.